# Tuple Relational Calculus: taking the results of one query and adding it to another

Tags: tuples, min, tuple-relational-calculus

I am looking to see how I can combine the results of one query into another expressed in TRC format.

> **Question**
>
> Retrieve the names of employees who make at least $10,000 more than
> the employee who is paid the least in the Company.
>
> **DB Setup**
>
> ```
> EMPLOYEE: fname , minit , lname, ssn , bdate , address , sex , salary , superssn , dno
> DEPARTMENT: dname dnumber , mgrssn , mgrstartdate
> DEPT_LOCATIONS: dnumber , dlocation
> PROJECT: pname , pnumber , plocation , dnum
> WORKS_ON: essn , pno , hours
> DEPENDENT: essn , dependent_name , sex , bdate , relationship
> ```

I have thus figured out so far how to find the employee with the minimum salary from the link [How would I find the highest/largest of something with relation algebra, domain relational calculus and tuple relational calculus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429131/how-would-i-find-the-highest-largest-of-something-with-relation-algebra-domain) and from http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr00/cs425/soln_from_text_midterm.pdf (page 32, question 6, 7, and 8 all use this logic with answers further down).

I am having difficulty taking the results of the minimum employee and then adding 10000 to it.  I believe the rest of the query should be simple.  I have the following to generate the minimum salary employee, but obviously this does not return employees above this.

```
{e1.salary |
       EMPLOYEE(e1)
   and NOT (∃e2) (EMPLOYEE(e2) and (e2.salary<e1.salary))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you can add 10000 to e2.salary directly in the condition i.e. e2.salary + 10000 < e1.salary

Comment: Thank you very much. That will certainly help with that question. However, I was using the same line of reasoning to solve a second question. The 2nd is... **Retrieve the names of all employees who work in the department that has the employee with the highest salary among all employees.**  In this new question, the only solution I can come up with is to pass the results by being explicit in my bound variable definition. In other words, something similar to

Comment: x.dnumber=((∃max.dno)(EMPLOYEE(max) and NOT (∃e2)(e2.salary > e1.salary))    where I am 'passing' the employee dept. number (∃max.dno) by defining it explicitly, similar to Domain Relational Calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further review, I think the following will solve 2nd question...

```
{emp.fname, emp.minit, emp.lname | EMPLOYEE(emp) and (∃x) ( EMPLOYEE(x) and NOT (x.salary>emp.salary)) and x.dno=emp.dno)}
```

While I may need to touch this up, I think it has the basic idea.  It is definitely somewhat removed coming from an OOP perspective and passing values up the chain.  Thanks again!